# Flask Error message persists even though I set it to none

Tags: python, flask

I am making a website with flask. This is my `/login`:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('userName')
        password = request.form.get('userPassword')
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user and check_password_hash(user.password_hash, password):
            return redirect(url_for('game'))
        else:
            error = 'Invalid username or password'
            return render_template('login.html', error=error)
    else:
        error = None
        return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

As you can see, when the user successfully enters his credentials, he gets redirected to `/game`. Should he enter the credentials false, I set the `error` var to `'Invalid username or password'` and display it on the login page using this code in my `.html`:

```
{% if error %}
    <div class="error">{{ error }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Now I have a very specific problem though when the user does these steps:

1. The user enters his credentials wrong and the message appears, just as wanted
2. The user enters his credentials right and gets redirected to '/game'
3. The user decides to go back to the login page and decides to click the back arrow in his browser

When this happens, the error message is still shown after the user goes back to `/login`. I thought I could solve the problem by setting `error` to `None`, but that didn't do anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Clicking back browser displays the cached page, doesnt trigger a new request to your flask. Start your flask app in development mode and see what happens when you click the back button

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this from happening, you can instruct the browser not to cache the login page. This can be achieved by adding response headers. Here is a modified version of your login function to include these headers:

```
from flask import make_response

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        response = make_response(render_template('login.html', error=None))
        response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
        response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
        response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
        return response
```

These headers tell the browser not to cache the page, forcing it to make a new GET request when the user navigates back, ensuring the error message is cleared.